# $_POST data from form being changed before entered into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

So new here to stack exchange but here goes nothing. So when I send a form to my apache server my data is only showing up as ones and zeros. Using var_dump[_$POST]; shows all of my data is correct before passing to MySQL.
My html form:

```
<form method="POST" action="submit.php" class="subForm">
        <input type="text" name = "item1" value="0">
        <input type="text" name="item2" value="0">
        <input type="text" name="item3" value="no">
        <input type="text" name="item4" value="no">
        <input type="text" name="item5" value="no">
        <input type="text" name="item6" value="no">
        <input type="submit" id = "form2">
    </form>
```

my php:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('*****','*****','*****','*****');
if(!$connect){
    die('Could not Connect: ' . mysqli_error($connect));
}
$NoR = isset($_POST["item1"]);
$CC = isset($_POST["item2"]);
$SD = isset($_POST["item3"]);
$HD = isset($_POST["item4"]);
$pack1 = isset($_POST["item5"]);
$pack2 = isset($_POST["item6"]);
$sql = "INSERT INTO form_test (item_1,item_2,item_3,item_4,item_5,item_6) VALUES (".$NoR.",".$CC.",".$SD.",".$HD.",".$pack1.",".$pack2.")";
mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
mysqli_close($connect);
var_dump($_POST)
```

var_dumb shows all data input is correct but in the table itself everything shows as 1s and 0s. Any advice?

Comment: Yep already on that. This currently is just for some simple form testing. Next step for me is to secure my form thanks again for the advice though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

isset will only give you if value is set or not. 1 if set else 0.

Use

```
if(isset($_POST["item1"])){
  $NoR = $_POST["item1"];`
}
```

**Updated: I made code for you to make sude ISSET values only goto INSERT query!**

```
$arrColumns = $arrValues = array();
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    $arrColumns[] =  key($key);
    $arrValues[] = $value; 
}
if(is_array($arrValues)){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO form_test (implode(',',$arrColumns)) 
           VALUES(implode(',',$arrValues)";
   mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
}
mysqli_close($connect);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer however, no go. taking isset out now no longer posts to db at all. giving me an undefined index error.

Comment: With this approach, He would need to validate before the sql statement if $Nor is set or not, thus, double validation.

Comment: Finally got it. Thank you all so much for your help!

Comment: @taxicala , I thought he will do it on his own ,Anyways I made code for him. Check update.

Answer (score 1):

In php, `isset` will return a `boolean` value (true if it's set, false if not), and when you try to print a `boolean` in php, it will display as 1 or 0. I suggest using the ternary comparison in your code, it's shorter and more readable than having a ton of `if` statements:

```
$NoR = isset($_POST["item1"]) ? $_POST["item1"] : '';
$CC = isset($_POST["item2"]) ? $_POST["item2"] : '';
$SD = isset($_POST["item3"]) ? $_POST["item3"] : '';
$HD = isset($_POST["item4"]) ? $_POST["item4"] : '';
$pack1 = isset($_POST["item5"]) ? $_POST["item5"] : '';
$pack2 = isset($_POST["item6"]) ? $_POST["item6"] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your HTML form

```
    <input type="text" name="action" value="submit">
```

And PHP code will be

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']) == 'submit') {
    $NoR = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["item1"]);
    $CC = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["item2"]);
    $SD = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["item3"]);
    $HD = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["item4"]);
    $pack1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["item5"]);
    $pack2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["item6"]);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO form_test (item_1,item_2,item_3,item_4,item_5,item_6) VALUES (".$NoR.",".$CC.",".$SD.",".$HD.",".$pack1.",".$pack2.")";
    mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    mysqli_close($connect);
    //var_dump($_POST)
}
```